# AS3 game element structure

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance

I'm trying to figure out how best to setup a kind of universal game element class for my game. What I want to try and create is a structure similar too..

GameElementPositionMovement (root class)
       ->GameElementVisual (handles all the graphics)
                ->GameElementPersonality (handles game logic)

I then want to be able to set up different personalities (monster, hero, icon etc) just by creating an instance of GameElementPersonality, but in it's constructor also be able to setup the visual and positioning/movement aspects as well.

I mentioned this in another question, and the answer that came back was...

> It seems that you need kind of 'data model' class to store logic and a
>   visual ('view') class. Visual class shouldn't inherit from data model,
>   it should use it. This is OOP related problem: IS vs HAS (inheritance
>   vs composition)

But I'm not sure if I understand that. The position/movement without any visual data, seems a good first root class, and then you add to that the visual aspects (GameElementVisual), and then finally you add in personality "traits" (GameElementPersonality) such as armour, damage, health etc

Therefore I'm keeping, the positioning/movement, visual and logic separate, and I presumed the heirachy that I've laid out would be the best way to do that, but is this not a good way to do this? should it be more flat? with the GameElementPositionMovement, creating both a visual and logic instance and storing that in itself?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a structure similar to this:

(pseudocode)
**ElementData**

```
//it doesn't have to extend any particular class
//however it would be nice if it could  dispatch events and register listeners
class ElementData implements IEventDispatcher
{
    public function ElementData() //constructor 
    {
        //do some stuff
    }

    public function setSomeProperty(value:int):void
    {
        //
    }

    public function doSomeCrazyStuff():void
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**ElementVisual**

```
class ElementVisual extends MovieClip //or just Sprite or even DiplayObjectContainer
{
    public function ElementVisual(elementData)
    {
        //constructor takes an instance of ElementData class

        elementData.addEventListener(CHANGE, onDataChange)

        elementData.doSomeCrazyStuff();
        if (userCliked)
        {
            elementData.setSomeProperty(15);
        }   

        //you can have here some interactions with user (keyboard, mouse)
        //then it can communicate with elenemtData and 'listen' what it says.
    }

    function onDataChange
    {
        //react accordingly
    }
}
```

**some visual representation (you may need many of these)**

```
class Monster extends ElementVisual
{
    //do all the graphic, animations etc
}
```

Then you need a class to set up all the data, visuals etc… In simplest implementation it can be the 'document class'.

It's not a proper MVC model - it's a simple example to show the concept of decoupling logic from visualisation.

MVC is not the only solution, there are other so called 'design patterns' which may be useful...

Comment: Very good with the examples and all, I like better than my own answer :).  Also totally agree other options are available, but this is a good place to start, it's not a choose only one type of situation.  I searched design patterns on google and wikipedia is okay, but I prefer diagrams which they seem to be lacking, image search worked out well http://tinyurl.com/d4l7qkj <--MVC http://tinyurl.com/bqtbs23 <-- Software Design Patterns.  Obviously goes well with a write up.  Also, agree to think when you're using patterns and if after things are stable you need to optimize think outside the box.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I'll look into what's been said, although I never really get using listeners for one class to communicate to another, it seems unnecessary extra work, when you can just call a method from one instance to another, I wonder if you have a lot of these going on if it's going to slow the game down.
Having said that, I'm currently also learning obj-c, so I'm trying to set my AS3 code up in such a way that I can set the same structures up in obj-c as well.

Comment: Event dispatcher pattern is very useful. It allows, in above example, the data model to be completely separated from its visual representation. The data class doesn't need to know that there is a visual representation, it just dispatches events when something happens. If the pattern is applied properly code is **less** complex than if the classes were communicating directly.

Comment: I know but in an arcade game, I don't see how it's a good idea for instances to be waiting on anything to happen, things need to be communicated instantly, but I can understand how it makes things more modular.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the idea with MVC is to keep things decoupled, in your case you're ultimately smashing everything into one chain of inheritance where you'll end up with one type of object that inherits all the properties from another object that inherits all the properties from another object, so you'll have an instance of this thing that represents everything, which is why this isn't a great pattern to go with.

If instead you have a GameElementPositionMovement class (Your main class) create an instance of the GameElementVisual and in instance of GameElementPersonality (or multiple instances if need be).  Then any time a change to a property is made in GameElementPersonality (or any in the collection if you choose to make a collection) could dispatch an event, the main class GameElementPositionMovement could listen for the dispatched event and when it gets it can set/pass the GameElementPersonality instance or array to the GameElementVisual.  Then in the GameElementVisual you're just dealing with drawing based on the current model all the time, the model is separated from the view logic, you'd also probably want to handle control in a separate class or in GameElementPositionMovement. (control being the modification of the model, in this case it would probably also be where you register listeners for user events, keyboard, mouse whatever)

This way the model remains clean of control logic and view logic, it's a clear separation of what goes where and really only the view sort of depends on the model and the controller sort of depends on the view but if interfaces are established for what the model view controller each need to communicate with each other in this way you can swap out any of those parts with a new class that implements the interface (not likely an issue in a small game, but the design lends itself to this ability and therefor future scalability).